# Finding latest timestamp per value across columns and rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a database table with rows like

```
Id | s1 | ts1 | s2 | ts2 | ... | s6 | ts6
```

Where ID is the non-unique identifier for the rows and will be used to filter the initial dataset. Fields `s1` to `s6` contain values and columns `ts1` to `ts6` contain their timestamps. And I need to find the latest (or first) timestamp per "s" value. The "s" values are not unique and the same values might be in any of the "s" columns.

I've not tried anything yet, because I have no idea how to turn those columns into rows. If I knew, then I'd probably find the latest (with max function) per value. But how to turn them into rows? I understand there is `PIVOT` function, but I'm not entirely sure how to use it and how to turn those columns into single "s" and "ts" columns.

Edit:

Sample dataset:

```
ID     s1 ts1        s2 ts2        s3 ts3        s4 ts4        s5 ts5        s6 ts6
123456 aa 1647456495 ab 1647456495 ac 1647456495 ad 1647456495 ae 1647456495 af 1647456495
123456 ax 1647456495 aa 1647456495 af 1647456495 al 1647456495 ai 1647456495 as 1647456495
123456 ab 1647456495 aa 1647456495 ad 1647456495 ac 1647456495 ae 1647456495 af 1647456495
```

Sample output:

```
s_value ts_value
aa      1647456495
ab      1647456495
af      1647456495
...
ax      1647456495
```

I used the same unix epoch timestamp in the example, but this is much what the data looks like. It's going to be about 20-100k rows per each dataset and 10-30 different values for "s" fields. Not sure if this is relevant or not.

Comment: Meaningful sample data and expected results will help us help you. The fact that you appear to be using denormalised data here is likely the problem, however, as you are on Azure SQL Database, then perhaps [`GREATEST`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-greatest-transact-sql?view=azure-sqldw-latest) will help you here.

Comment: Updated the question with a sample dataset and a tiny bit more information.

Comment: *"sample data **and expected results** will help us help you"*

Comment: maybe also include "why did you design your table like this instead of a single s and ts pair of columns since that seems to be how you want to query your data"?

Comment: Added the expected output.  @ConorCunninghamMSFT If I had designed this, I'd done it better. Not used UNIX timestamps and so on. It's just the thing I have to work with as it is, unfortunately.

Comment: This is a mess since the columns don't line up at all.  I suggest you consider doing select s1, ts1 from T UNION ALL select s2, ts2 from T ... for all columns.  While you are at it, put that into a table like that since it will be more useful going fwd

Comment: OK so basically select s1 as s_value, ts1 as ts_value from .... union all select s2 as s_value and so on? And then do the usual SQL stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Conor Cunningham MSFT for the suggestion, this would be a good solution. I have reproed and got the expected results and posting it as the answer.

**Source:**

[image]

```
-- get the distinct values of 's' and 't' columns
select s1 as s_values, t1 as t_values  into #temp_latest from test_tb 
union  
select s2, t2 from test_tb
union  
select s3, t3 from test_tb
union 
select s4, t4 from test_tb
union 
select s5, t5 from test_tb
union 
select s6, t6 from test_tb

-- to get the max t values for same s value
select s_values, max(t_values) t_values from #temp_latest 
group by s_values
```

[image]